# Devise Login Not Processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

So I've got an app using Devise in which the sign up (registrations#create) is functioning, however the sign in (sessions#create) is not working whatsoever. First off, none of the validation errors are being shown even if all fields are left blank. In all instances (proper login credentials and incorrect credentials) the page is simply refreshed without the create action being called.

sessions#new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :autocomplete => "off", :class => 'login-form') do |f| %>
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control', :style => 'width: 300px; background-color: white;', :id => 'input', :autofocus => true %></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, :style => 'width: 300px; background-color: white;', :class => 'form-control', :id => 'input' %></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
<div><%= f.check_box :remember_me, :style => 'width: 300px; background-color: white;', :class => 'form-control', :id => 'input' %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
<% end -%>
</div>
<div><%= f.submit "Sign in", :class => "btn btn-default" %></div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Logs

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-16 12:39:27 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jYBcVamyNJDNxIgm6MiO0bBq/G/mMn/1dO4pJNAbm68=", "user"=>{"email"=>"raphi@qmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jYBcVamyNJDNxIgm6MiO0bBq/G/mMn/1dO4pJNAbm68=", "user"=>{"email"=>"raphi@qmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.4ms)
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 98ms (Views: 18.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The logs aren't telling me all too much and I'm a bit lost on how to assess/deal with this issue. If anyone has an idea your feedback would be much appreciated.

Cheers,